# When using Rigify, Is there a way to add more bones to the lips?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I want more control on the lips. However, when I subdivide the bones in the metarig I get errors when I try to generate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to generate the rig first, then you can modify it as you want: better adding bones, withouy deleting or dividing anything, unless you know exactly what you're doing, because Rigify rig is quite complex, with lots of auxiliary and machinary bones.